# How does one add sequential numbers to the date numbers on for loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, for-loop, grep

For example I have the following FOR loop on linux shell bash.

```
for log in filename.log.2014-11-0[123456789].gz; do
    printf '%s:' "$log"
    gzcat "$log" | grep -wc 'burgers for 1 dollar'
done
```

I would like to make the numbers loop for all the dates's data as per below:

```
for log in filename.log.201[45]-0[123456789]-0[123456789].gz; do
    printf '%s:' "$log"
    gzcat "$log" | grep -wc 'burgers for 1 dollar'
done
```

Comment: Why not just `filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz`?

Comment: Do you really just want the months up to September, and the single-digit days in those months? Or do you want all months and all days?

Comment: all months and all dates @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You can use range in BASH:

```
for log in filename.log.201{4,5}-0{1..9}-0{1..9}.gz; do
    printf '%s:' "$log"
    gzcat "$log" | grep -wc 'burgers for 1 dollar'
done
```

**EDIT:** You may just need this glob pattern in for loop: (Thanks to @Barmar)

```
filename.log.201{4,5}-*-*.gz
```

Comment: Why all the quotes around the literal filename?

Comment: Fixed it now, I had `shopt -s nullglob` and due to that was not getting any output earlier.

Comment: Note that this will get an error from `gzcat` if any dates are missing `[1-9]` instead of `{1..9}` will match against existing files.

Comment: Hmm in that case `filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz` will be better glob

Comment: What about if you only wants date from November 2014 up to and including 01 February 2015?

Comment: It is not straight forward to match date range using shell glob. If you show some examples in question I can suggest something.

Comment: Hi,
How do I add multiple strings to search the same file for:

Currently:

    #!/bin/bash
    
    for log in filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz; do
        printf '%s:' "$log"
        zcat "$log" | grep -wc 'dollar for dollars'
    done

Desired result:

    #!/bin/bash
    
    for log in filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz; do
        printf '%s:' "$log"
        echo "count for dollar for dollars"
        zcat "$log" | grep -wc 'dollar for dollars'
  
        echo "count for pollar for pollars"
        zcat "$log" | grep -wc 'pollar for pollars'
    done

Comment: It is difficult to understand your code from comments. Can you post it in question to clarify where are you stuck?